# Git-Jenkins Integration Error

Tags: git, jenkins

I have completed Jenkins installation but when I try to do *'Build Now'* in Jenkins (for the project residing in the Git repository), the following error appears, not allowing for successful execution:

```
> There's no such executable git.exe in PATH: C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client/, C:/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client/,
> C:/WINDOWS/system32, C:/WINDOWS, C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem,
> C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/, C:/Program Files
> (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL, C:/Program
> Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL, C:/Program
> Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT,
> C:/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT,
> C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.dnx/bin, C:/Program
> Files/Microsoft DNX/Dnvm/,
> C:/Users/Pratibha/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps, C:/Program
> Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin, C:/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin.
```

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Looks like you have not installed a git client

Comment: can you please let me know more about it, i am using Git (UI part from Eclipse), externally i need to install anything, please elaborate more on git installation part of Git client, any guide or any step by step reference on the same.

Comment: Look at Google. i think there you will find a lot

Comment: Sure and Thanks, i am new to it so not much aware off....only Git client is missing or any other things as well?

Comment: The error message is about git. I think git Client Installation will solve your Problem. But as i do not know your System i can not say if you Need more. Install a git Client and see if you get other messages

Comment: installation i complete, i also provided path of the same in jenkins -> Add GIt column along with java and maven, In system properties-> environment variables-> i need to put this git path?

Comment: I do not know it. try it

Comment: Thanks it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using windows check the system environment path, whether the git path is available over there and also add the git installation path to Global Environment Setting in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine, my execution was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `/git/install/bin` your system `PATH` environment variable

or

you need to enable **Inject environment variables to the build process**, then do the following

**Properties File Path :** /git/install/path

**Properties Content :** git.exe

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine, my execution was successful.